# How to drag drop elements into svg group

Tags: d3.js

I have few circles on left and a svg group on the right. I want to drag the circles in to svg group on drag drop. Once I drop the element into svg group, it should be appended to the group.

So far I have a created a draggable elements and draggable groups but not able find any article on the same.

I have few circles on left and a svg group on the right. I want to drag the circles in to svg group on drag drop. Once I drop the element into svg group, it should be appended to the group.

So far I have a created a draggable elements and draggable groups but not able find any article on the same.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/wowunoluza/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Editor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 800)
                        .attr("height", 803);

                var sidebar = svgContainer.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 0)
                        .attr("y", 43.5)
                        .attr("width", 69)
                        .attr("height", 620)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style("fill", "none");

                var rect = svgContainer.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 10)
                        .attr("y", 50)
                        .attr("width", 51)
                        .attr("height", 41)
                        .attr("rx", 10)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .style("fill", "none");

                //Draw the Circle
                var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 35)
                        .attr("cy", 145)
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
                        .style("stroke", "green")
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .style("fill", "white");

                var circle2 = svgContainer.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 35)
                        .attr("cy", 225)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("stroke", "red")
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .attr("r", 25);

                var circle3 = svgContainer.append("circle")
                        .attr("id", "circleToClone")
                        .attr("cx", 35)
                        .attr("cy", 310)
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .style("stroke", "#CDB483");

                var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function () {
                            var g = this;
                            return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                                y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
                        })
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {

                            g = this;
                            console.log(g);
                            translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                            x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                                    y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
                            d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        });

                var group = svgContainer.append("g")
                        .attr("id", "mygroup")
                        .call(dragGroup)
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

                group.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 250)
                        .attr("y", 250)
                        .attr("width", 151)
                        .attr("height", 141)
                        .attr("rx", 10)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style("fill", "white");

                group.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 330)
                        .attr("cy", 330)
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .style("stroke-width", 1)
                        .style("stroke", "red");


                var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function ()
                        {
                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy")};
                        })

                        .on('dragend', function (d) {
                            var mouseCoordinates = d3.mouse(this);
                            if (mouseCoordinates[0] > 170) {
                                //Append new element
                                var circle2 = d3.select("svg").append("circle")
                                        .classed("drg", true)
                                        .attr("cx", 100)
                                        .attr("cy", 100)
                                        .attr("r", 20)
                                        .attr("cx", mouseCoordinates[0])
                                        .attr("cy", mouseCoordinates[1])
                                        .style("fill", "white")
                                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                                        .style("stroke", "#CDB483");
                            }
                        });
                circle.call(drag);
                circle2.call(drag);
                circle3.call(drag);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                <h1 id="title">Editor</h1>
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's probably a more efficient way to do this (perhaps a built in d3 command/something relating to collisions?), but the first thing that springs to mind would be to run through all of the group elements on your page, and using `r` for circles and `width, height` for rectangles, determine if the mouse is within that group (design a short algorim to determine min x,y and max x,y). It'd be a little complex since `cx, cy` defines the middle of a circle and `x, y` defines the corner of a `rect`, but this is the general idea.

Comment: The function `getBBox()` looks useful. It gives coordinates relative to the `g` element that the shape is a member of, so you'd have to use `g.attr("transform")` and offset coordinates by the `translate(x,y)`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/3rDPC/3/) is a Fiddle showing `getBBox()` in action.

Comment: @JSBob Is this better to achieve this using collision detection? I am not find any tutorial on collision detection. Its only code example every where

Answer (score 1):

When "dropping" a circle, you could use `d3.transform` to get the current translation of the `g` element and then check if the mouse's coordinates lies within the rectangle in the group.

Then you can append a new circle to `group` where its coordinates are determined by the mouse's coordinates and the group's translation and it's stroke by the stroke of the circle that had been dragged to the group.

So your `.on("dragend"` function should now look like this:

```
var mouseCoordinates = d3.mouse(this);
var groupTransform = d3.transform(group.attr("transform"));
var groupX = groupTransform.translate[0];
var groupY = groupTransform.translate[1];
var rect = group.select("rect");
var rectX = +rect.attr("x");
var rectY = +rect.attr("y");
var rectWidth = +rect.attr("width");
var rectHeight = +rect.attr("height");

if (mouseCoordinates[0] > groupX + rectX 
    && mouseCoordinates[0] < groupX + rectX + rectWidth
    && mouseCoordinates[1] > groupY + rectY
    && mouseCoordinates[1] < groupY + rectY + rectHeight) {
    //Append new element
    var newCircle =   group.append("circle")
        .classed("drg", true)
        .attr("cx", mouseCoordinates[0] - groupX)
        .attr("cy", mouseCoordinates[1] - groupY)
        .attr("r", 20)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", d3.select(this).style("stroke"));
}
```

There are still many things you could change and add to your code to make it better, but this should get you started.

Comment: I didn't understand the mousecoordinates part. Why we are using static values there? Is it possible to use `getBBox()` function as mentioned by JSBob above?

Comment: I guess collision detection is way to go for this??

Comment: I used static values because I assumed that the `rect`'s coordinates and size wasn't going to change. I've updated my answer to get the `rect`'s coordinates and size dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to d3 js. I didn't know I can select on group also. For now this should work ;)

Comment: Dropping the circles on to rectangle on right side y axis is not working properly. It is pushing away the circle out side the rectangle

Comment: Adding a first circle is working fine but adding a second circle to group is pushing the circle outside the box